# Vuejs - Object notation for refs

Tags: vue.js

I want to group my refs in to an object and access them by object notation. With that in mind, I now have this component:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <input ref="input.name" type="text"/>
      <input ref="input.email" type="email"/>
      <input ref="input.password" type="password"/>
    </div>
  `,
  created(){
    console.log(this.$refs["input.name"]); // This works fine
    console.log(this.$refs.input.name); // throws "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"
  }
})
```

But it only shows this:

```
{
    input.name: input,
    input.email: input,
    input.password: input,
}
```

What I want is something like this:

```
{
    input: {
        name: input,
        email: input,
        password: input,
    },
}
```

Check fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xutzpv7f/2/)

> Update:
>
> I'm well aware of `v-model` but that's not what I need, I'll be doing something else with DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      inputs: {}
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <input ref="input.name" type="text" value="123"/>
      <input ref="input.email" type="email"/>
      <input ref="input.password" type="password"/>
      <button type="button" @click="clickMe">Click ME</button>
    </div>
  `,
  mounted() {
    this.setRefs();
    console.log("this.inputs", this.inputs);
  },
  methods: {
    setRefs() {
      const INPUTS = {};
      for (key in this.$refs) {
        if (key.indexOf(".")) {
          const KEYS_LIST = key.split(".");
          INPUTS[KEYS_LIST[0]] = INPUTS[KEYS_LIST[0]] || {};
          INPUTS[KEYS_LIST[0]][KEYS_LIST[1]] = this.$refs[key];
        }
      }
      this.inputs = INPUTS;
    },
    
    clickMe() {
      console.log("this.inputs.input.name.value", this.inputs.input.name.value);
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Will the refs in the `this.inputs`sync with the actual refs states?

Comment: if you have only these three inputs, then this.inputs - sync. You can change value in input 'name' and click button.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot work: refs only support strings as keys (see the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref)), so there is not way of using objects here.

Also, a string with "dot notation" does not magically transform into an object with a nested property -- it's just a string. You could work around this by manually parsing the ref strings into an object structure, as has been demonstrated by @Ilia Brykin's answer. But I honestly think that you are misunderstanding the purpose of the whole ref system if you really want to do that.

P.S.: If you drop the "dort notation" part, you could use keys like `input_name` and access them via `this.$refs.input_name`.

**EDIT**

Another idea: you can get all input refs by their common prefix.

```js
Object.keys(this.$refs).filter(ref => ref.startsWith('input.')
```

This gives you an array of ref strings of input elements.

Comment: Well that sucks. I wanted to group those refs so that I could create a computed value that iterates around the `this.$refs.input` group and return a certain value based on the DOM. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Ah, now I better understand your goal. I updated my answer, I hope it's helpful to you.

Comment: Yeah, I'll go with @Ilia Brykin's answer though. I still need to access them like `this.$refs.input.name`. I really appreciate your time :D